# Replace Numeric values with NA

Tags: r

I am writing a function that takes in some vector and checks if it is numeric. If it is false, it will replace the numeric values with NA in the else statement. I have tried using the is.numeric() function in many ways, without much luck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
test <- function(x){


if(is.numeric(x) == TRUE){
  mean.x <- mean(x)
  vectorlist <- list(mean.x)
  }
else

return(vectorlist)
}
x <- c("a", 1, 2)
test(x)
```

Comment: So I think the fundamental misunderstanding here is that vectors can only ever contain elements of a single type. You might type `x <- c("a", 1, 2)` but if you check, the result is all characters. So if `is.numeric(x)` is TRUE, then all the elements are numeric.

Comment: If the vector contains anything other than I number, I don't want it to take the mean. So, if I ran it with x, I would want it to return "a" NA NA

Comment: Ok, but you do realize that `x` consists of three *characters*, "a", "1" and "2". Not the number 1 or the number 2? Your comment seems to imply that what you really want is to take a vector, and if it isn't numeric, replace all values that *can be converted* to numbers with NAs?

Comment: ...for example, you seem to be describing something like this: `x[!is.na(as.numeric(x))] <- NA`.

Comment: Yes, it converts the rest of the values to the type of the first value correct? That is what I want to do.

Comment: Well, technically it converts the whole vector to whatever is the "least common denominator type", it doesn't matter what position in the vector the values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a function roughly like this:

```
test <- function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){
        return(mean(x))
    }
    else{
        x[!is.na(as.numeric(x))] <- NA
        return(x)
    }
}
x <- c("a", 1, 2)
test(x)
```

Note that `if (is.numeric(x))` is sufficient, you don't need the `== TRUE` stuff in the if clause.